# Using conditional feature compilation/inclusion for release versioning

Tags: programming-practices, project-management, testing, version-control, development-process

I have been playing with the following idea: commonly when different release series (1.0.x, 1.1.x, development code) of a product are maintained in parallel one uses different branches within a version control system to develop them.  In theory though one could use feature macros (written from a C/C++ point of view, but the idea should be portable) to enable or disable particular features based on the version which is being built.  In C/C++ this would most likely mean enclosing code for new features in `#ifdef FEATURE_X` and either enabling or disabling them on the build command line or having a master header file containing code like

```
#if version > 101
# define FEATURE_X
# define FEATURE_Y
#endif
```

Back-porting features, if one needs to do so, could be done by rearranging this file.

The idea behind this is that normally one will want to back-port fixes and improvements which are not part of significant new features to older versions unless one has a specific reason not to.  However, these back-ports are often done in a rather haphazard way, resulting in unintended subtle differences between versions or forgotten fixes in certain versions.  The feature macro approach reverses things, by making back-porting the default and explicitly marking code sections which are not for back-porting.  While it would not be a silver bullet by any means, it might improve the level of stability which one would achieve with a given amount of testing.  I would also expect it to improve code structure by forcing cleaner separation of different features.

So the question: does anyone know of real-world data about this or similar approaches?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: The usual way to distinguish different releases in the same code base is to make branches for them. So what you're really asking is "is conditional compilation better for releases than branching?". You might want to include that term into your question title.

Comment: You can find examples of this in pretty much any Lua module written in C intended to work with both Lua 5.1 and 5.2.

Comment: Hey: isn't that more a single version and binary of the module intended to plug into two different environments?

Comment: What do you mean by "different major versions"? Do you mean that both the 1.x and 2.x releases are under active maintenance, or that the user can choose different versions of a software product with different feature sets?

Comment: Bart, I meant the first.  You are right "different major versions" is not the best way to express it.  What about "different release series"?  Or any thought how I could express it more clearly?

Comment: This strikes me as a bad idea. It's uncommon that you want to backport features, but when you do, you will want them to actually work so there's no need to conditional them.

Comment: Please clarify with a small example: say you have a C++ project built by makefiles; you want to be able to compile two version with different features on the same branch? For instance, `make --version=1.0 && make --version=1.1`, and the code is full of macros like `#if VERSION <= 1.0`?

Comment: Telastyn, logc, I have edited the description - is that now clearer?  Telastyn, back-porting features may not be common (though we do do it reasonably often), but there are generally lots of little fixes and improvements which do need back-porting.  logc, we already wrap nearly all new feature code in macros anyway so that different developers can enable/disable them as they choose at development and testing time.

Comment: @michaeljt - sure but things that are really fixes or clear improvements should always be on... No reason to complicate your code for no benefit.

Comment: @Telastyn - I clearly wasn't clear enough in my description.  The whole idea is that only the new features are conditional, and everything else unconditional.  Precisely so that they are picked up by every supported version without needing explicit back-porting.

Comment: @michaeljt - which I can't imagine you regularly doing. Not only is it technically difficult to isolate features well enough to do this, you're increasing your testing burden significantly while also decreasing the motivation for customers to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more common to use source control branching in order to control what features are available within a particular version of the software.

That said, applications that offer tiered functionality within the same version level will sometimes use the technique you describe.  Usually, you'll see two main uses of the conditional definitions.  The fist uses of the `#define`s declares the per-tier functionality for that tier's build.  The second usage is throughout the code where the per-tier functionality actually needs to be enabled.

In other cases, backwards compatibility on an otherwise breaking change can be maintained through the use of `#define`s and the application version.  This gets a bit more tricky and yields less easily maintained code, but is a convenient way of keeping all the relevant code together in a single branch.  The developer has to remember to revert the version number when making a special, backwards compatible build, but it does allow the older code to remain inline with the rest of the source code.

Comment: Thank you.  I will wait for a bit before accepting this in case other people answer.  Unfortunately my reputation on "programmers" is not yet high enough to up-vote this.  I'm not quite sure I follow the last bit though about reverting the version number for a backwards-compatible change.